# local time for datetime field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, timezone

I have a model, that has a Datetime field

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

...
created_at = models.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

the settings.py for timezone configuration:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

I have two questions:

first, how can I display local time, when I want to display created_at in admin

second, also, when I use it in serializer:

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (..., 'created_at',)
```

Note: My app have users from different countries.

**I actually want the user's timezone from client**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I cannot find user's local timezone in django or django rest. I just store datetime in UTC format on db and then convert it in local timezone in frontend. My frontend is Angular 5.0. Then I can use **date** pipline for this converting.

Formats a date value according to locale rules.

```
{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}
```

Sample:

```
{{ created_at | date: 'short' }}
```

output: **8/5/18, 3:15 PM**